# How to use different data using faker in Java by using functions?

Tags: java, arrays, faker

Am using faker with Java (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker/0.2) and have issue in generating different data in loop using function. Here is my code:

```
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class DataGenerator{
 Faker faker = new Faker();
 LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   generatedata("firstname");
   //generatedata("lastname");
   for(String key : this.result.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(key);
        ArrayList<String> al = this.result.get(key);
        for(String s : al)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
 }

 public void generatedata(String fieldType) throws Exception{
   switch (fieldType.toLowerCase()){
    case "firstname":
      resultdata = generateInvalidData(faker.name().firstName());
      break;
    case "lastname":
      resultdata = generateInvalidData(faker.name().lastName());
      break;
   }
   result.put(fieldType.toLowerCase(), resultdata);
 }

 public ArrayList<String> generateNames(String fieldType) throws Exception{
  ArrayList<String> resultdata = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        //valid data
        resultdata.add(testData);

        //UPPERCASE
        resultdata.add(testData.toUpperCase());
    }
     return resultdata;
 }
```

Here am trying to generate firstname, lastname with different count and combination in **generateNames** method/function but since the faker is called only once which is passed as parameter am getting same set of data.

I don't want to call content of **generateNames** in **generatedata** method because if i want to add more combinations then i have to copy paste everything in each switch case if more cases are added. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why not do something like `generateInvalidData(new Faker().name().firstName());` so it's a new instance of a Faker object every time you grab the first name, last name and so on?

Comment: Its still showing same data.

Comment: is there any possibility that i can pass **name()** class and **firstname** method as parameters and invoke new instance of faker in `generateInvalidData()` method ?